# XPiNC 8.5.3 - Time Value shows Incorrectly

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpinc

I have opened the document in the XPiNC (Version 8.5.3), the time values are showing wrongly.

Note : Same I have tested [image]in version(Version 8.5.2), there its seems to be correct.

I have checked the values in document properties, the values are saved correctly.

I am really confused on this, Should I need to do any settings for this...?

Even I have tried with other PC with 8.5.3 version, there also I got same Issue :-((

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your time zone setting?

Comment: My PC Time Zone setting is GMT+05:30..

Comment: Time Zone setting all are seems to be correct, the same machine I have opened the document in XPiNC with NotesClient Version 8.5.2 yesterday,that time it was correct.

Comment: Today I upgraded to Notes Client 8.5.3 in my PC and opened the document in XPiNC, this mismatch timing happening....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8.5.3 has had a couple of reported regression bugs related to time zones in XPages.

here's one that we encountered with viewColumn, similar to yours it seems to have appeared with 8.5.3. However, these problems (APAR LO67745 and LO72278) seem to be in date time fields saved with no time component or no date component.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO72278

The same problem also exists in domino 9.0.

The fix for this was in 8.5.3 Fixpack 3, which I just verified. No fix for 9.0 yet.

Answer (score 2):

I guess, there are different settings for time zone on clients and server. To make sure you use always the same time zone set value "Time Zone" in "Application properties" / "XPages" to `Server`.

More information about this topic available at http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPagesTimeZones.htm

Update:

As mentioned in your comment, it does work for 8.5.2 XPiNC but not for 8.5.3. I assume you tested both on same computer in same session. Then the difference must be in Notes client installation.
Do you have the same time zone settings in current location document in 8.5.2 and 8.5.3?

[image]

Comment: I don't think so. Because I have tested the same in version 8.5.2 & 8.5.3

It only happening in XPiNC(version NotesClient 8.5.3) not in browser.

Note: I have also tested in two different server, there also this happened in version 8.5.3, but not in 8.5.2

Comment: Do you have same time zone settings in current location document?

Comment: I have in the Location document, Yes option only selected, Advanced-> Basics->Use operating Systems time zone settings -> Yes

Comment: ...for both versions 8.5.2 and 8.5.3? Are both versions running on same PC in same session (fat client, VM, Citrix...)?

Comment: Yes Same Machine, but not Same session. Today I upgrade 8.5.2 to 8.5.3, then only I faced this Issue

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue with our servers. One of them was 2 hours off. As it turned out, the problem started at the time of Windows server setup. Default time zone was GMT+0, then changed to GMT+1 (and second hour was because of DLS). Administrator installing the server saw correct setting, but that initial GMT+0 was stored somewhere in registry and used by System account Domino run with.

So it seems you should double check regional settings of the client machine's operating system.
http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server/jsi-tip-0311-regional-settings-registry

Look for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT` paths.