# ViewPanel does not honor Time Zone on Date-only field

Tags: jsf, timezone, xpages, lotus-domino

We have an app running on 8.5.3 servers (windows) with a field set as Date-only in the Notes backend. No time component gets saved. There is a list style Xpage with a ViewPanel that displays these dates from a Notes view data source, and a form that opens from a link in that view that also shows the same field in the linked record. We are in North America.

After UTC midnight, which is 7 pm Eastern, all of the date column values shown in the view will roll back to the previous day. The linked document in the form-oriented Xpage still shows the proper date as can be seen in a Notes client, and in a Notes info box showing hidden field values.

The XSP application property setting for "Time Zone" has no effect on this behavior.
I added time zone to the display format pattern (MM/dd/YYYY vv) in the viewPanel and also to the field in the form's panel, and both are showing the same time zone, GMT -4. So the date displayed in the viewPanel is in error, as far as I can tell.

I also have verified the same behavior on a Domino 9 server. Is there a workaround for the view list or should we try it on 8.5.2?

Comment: We have had similar issues near midnight too. What OS your server uses? In Windows, check registry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540872/xpinc-8-5-3-time-value-shows-incorrectly/17543325#17543325

Comment: We have a few flavors on Windows 2003 and 2008, 32 and 64. It happens on all of them. I did find a work-around: this tip from Denny on another thread made it go away. I could not upvote it since I am not worthy. Just add the explicit TimeZone attribute of "UTC". This seems completely backwards and it worked, now the view column is showing in EDT.     http://stackoverflow.com/a/13909018/1337544

Comment: And finally, I found an IBM ticket on this, which they claim is a duplicate of another prob concerning the time pciker control and the other issue fixed in FP3.  Hope so.    LO72278: XPAGES VIEW DATE BEHIND ONE DAY AFTER 7 PM http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO72278

Comment: Also readn this related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115961/dates-are-adjusted-for-users-only-at-midnight-on-my-xpages